# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'

Tags: arrays, string, error-handling, nsarray

```
if let cityDetailsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Places", ofType: "plist") {
            if let cityDetails = NSArray(contentsOfFile: cityDetailsPath!) as? [[String: String]]
            {
                    for city in cityDetails
```

I have an error in the Line:

```
if let cityDetails = NSArray(contentsOfFile: cityDetailsPath!) as? [[String: String]]
```

Error:

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove force unwrapping symbol !.

```
if let cityDetailsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Places", ofType: "plist") {
        if let cityDetails = NSArray(contentsOfFile: cityDetailsPath) as? [[String: String]]
        {
            for city in cityDetails {

            }
        }
    }
```